# Type parameter 'java.long.Long' is not within its bounds;

Tags: android, realm

I have a problem figuring out what am I doing wrong. Any suggestions?  `RealmList` of `Long` shows the error:

```
 "Type parameter 'java.long.Long' is not within its bounds; 
   should implement 'io.realm.RealmModel'".
```

**BodyForCreateInvoice.java :**

```
    public class BodyForCreateInvoice extends RealmObject{

        @SerializedName("labelIds")
        @Expose
        private RealmList<Long> labelIds = null;

    }
```

Comment: `RealmList<Primitive>` is not supported. You should use a `RealmObject`, like `RealmList<Label>`.

Comment: We are currently working on the feature, and you can track it at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/575

Comment: ok, thanks for the answers, I'll try to use workaround with RealmObject